# $\ln(0)$ in particular solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{1+x^2}{x(1+\sin3y)}
$$

I found the general solution by using separation of variables technique : $$
y = \ln(x) + \frac{x^2}{x} - y + \frac{1}{3}\cos3y + C
$$

Steps:
$$
\frac{1+x^2}{x(1+\sin 3y)} \equiv \frac{1+x^2}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{1+\sin 3y}
$$

$$
\int (1+\sin 3y)\;\mathrm{d}y = \int\left(\frac{1}{x}+x\right)\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
I have to plug the values $y = 1$ and $x = 0$ to find the particular solution. But since the general solution has $\ln(x)$, it's invalid if I plug $0$ in. So how do I get rid of the $\ln(0)$, do I have to use L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: can you Show us your steps?

Comment: added the steps

Comment: It's not correctly integrated.

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: The right-hand side of your ODE is undefined at $x = 0$. Are you certain the problem is correctly stated/rendered here?

Comment: The question im doing states values x=0 y=1, unless there is a way to solve further with the ln(0) then the question is wrong.

Comment: I wonder if they accidentally transcribed that and it should be $y(1) = 0$.

Comment: $y = \ln(x) + \frac{x^2}{\color{red}{2}}  + \frac{1}{3}\cos3y + C$ ?